# Ubuntu 16.04.1: Why are some programs started by both systemd AND initV systems?

Tags: systemd, init, sysvinit

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.1 with `nginx` installed, and when  dpkg installed nginx, it registered the boot time config in two locations.

#### Systemd location

systemd config which states to start nginx daemon on boot (or "multi-user target")

```
% ls -l /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service                       
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service -> /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service
```

#### Init V location

initV config which states to start nginx daemon on boot (or "run level 5")

```
% ls -l /etc/rc5.d/S02nginx
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Apr  2 23:27 /etc/rc5.d/S02nginx -> ../init.d/nginx
```

If I disable nginx, systemd gives some output indicating some kind of backward compatibility actions are occuring

```
% sudo systemctl disable  nginx.service  
Synchronizing state of nginx.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable nginx
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `nginx' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `nginx' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

This will remove BOTH the symlinks from above.
Why is this setup this way? Why isn't there just one or the other - either the new systemd config or the old systemV init?

Comment: Because Ubuntu inherits this stuff from Debian where alternate init systems are supported.

Comment: @jordanm I can understand that alternate init systems need to be supported because many programs in the apt package ecosystem and in the linux/unix ecosystem in general would expect the init scripts to be available during a session, but during boot, shouldnt only one mechanism be necessary to start a daemon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [jordanm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/13796/jordanm) comments, this is inherited from Debian where different init systems are supported. Not only that, but you can change your init system without reinstalling, and expect your configuration to survive — including which services are enabled or disabled. That’s the reason why the systemd and `sysvinit` setups are kept in sync. (Note that at least some of the features being used are provided by upstream systemd and aren’t Debian- or Ubuntu-specific.)

Comment: thanks, do you know if Debian have documentation about this? I'm guessing in order to achieve this ability to swap init systems, all the packages on the system (which have init scripts/configs registered) must need to be syncronised in this way - that must add alot more work for the package maintainers?

Comment: It doesn’t add much work, it’s handled by [`dh_systemd`](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/pkg-systemd/Packaging). The runtime behaviour is mostly provided by [upstream](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). [Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html) describes the `update-rc.d`/`invoke-rc.d` commands, which cope with all the available init systems in Debian.